# Is $(\omega+1)^\omega/{\cal U}$ "unique"?

Tags: lattices, posets, ultrapowers

If ${\cal U}_i$  free ultrafilters on $\omega$ for $i = 1,2$ , are the ultrapowers $(\omega+1)^\omega/{\cal U}_i$ necessarily isomorphic as lattices for $i = 1,2$?

Comment: What do you mean "as lattices"? It's a linear order.

Comment: If CH holds, yes. If CH fails, no. See the reference I posted under your (now deleted) question yesterday.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0406v1) is the reference I was talking about. The CH fails case is Theorem 1.